# PDO SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Before anyone asks me... Yes the column definitely exists.

The following query works fine from the CLI or PHPMyAdmin, but when executing in PDO it doesnt work, it says the column doesn't exist.

```
SELECT      `draw_config`.`draw_config_id`, `draw_config`.`time_zone`
FROM        `draw_config`
```

Full Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'draw_config.draw_config_id' in 'field list'

I have recently upgraded my local dev environment, including PHP & MySQL, so no doubt that's the problem.

**Does anyone have any more information/solution for this error or bug?**

I'm running on Windows 8 with the following...

*PHP Version:*

```
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2013 11:33:44) VC11
```

*MySQL Version:*

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.14                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.14                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Without doubt this is an error in your code. Since you haven't posted any, it's difficult to know what to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Before anyone asks me... Yes the column definitely exists.

Quite contrary, it is definitely **not**.

One of most essential programmer's skills is **ability to trust their eyes.** No kidding.

When a program tells you there is no such field - you'd better trust your eyes and start looking for one. Check your naming, letter case, database credentials and all that stuff. Community can do very little with this kind of errors.

Comment: Honestly, I know how it sounds, but I copy/pasted the query from the IDE into PHPMyAdmin and it works. This is the same exact query that I'm testing.

Comment: I Take that back. Although my query was the same, I was testing against the wrong database. Whoops!

Comment: If I could, I would star this answer!  Very sobering as an engineer, when you encounter an issue like this..